# concatenate text values to access array item in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function in php that will read from an array.  I am trying to concatenate text and the array id number, to read the value in the array, however it is the concatenated text that is being returned, not the value of the array.

Here is my code:

```
//arrays with words in dictionary

$dictionary_word1 = array("test1","test2","test3");

$dictionary_word2 = array("test4","test5","test6");

$dictionary_word3 = array("test7","test8","test9");


$word_to_lookup = "dictionary_word_1"; 
//value to send to function

$returned_word = convert_word($word_to_lookup); 
//value returned from function

echo "<br>the returned word from the function is " . $returned_word; 
//the text "$dictionary_word_1[2]" is displayed instead of array value

echo "<br>the value in the array is " . $dictionary_word1[2];  
//this displays correcty as "test3"

function convert_word($word_to_convert)
{
    global $dictionary_word1;   
    $converted_word = '$'.$word_to_convert .'[2]';  
    return $converted_word;
}
```

Could anyone give me any tips on where I am going wrong?

Comment: `$converted_word = ${$word_to_convert}[2];`  But there are better ways to do whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the variable this way to do what you are trying (see [PHP: Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and [PHP: Variable Parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)):

```
$converted_word = ${$word_to_convert}[2];
```

However, notice the difference between `dictionary_word_1` and `$dictionary_word1`?  Won't work.

Regardless, anytime you're doing this you would be better with an array.  In this case a multidimensional array.  Consider:

```
$words[1] = array("test1","test2","test3");
$words[2] = array("test4","test5","test6");
$words[3] = array("test7","test8","test9");
```

Then you're always using `$words` just changing the index and then using a word from that array.

Comment: Thanks very much.  The curly brackets worked and thanks for spotting the extra underscore.  Working as expected.  I'm just learning php and playing about with functions.  I will test out multidimensional arrays.

Comment: NP.  Any experienced person here will tell you, if you are trying to dynamically create or access a variable name, then you should be using an array.